# Calculating distance between borders when one polygon inside another polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, distance, analysis

I am brand new to ArcGIS and having some trouble. I would like to calculate the distances between the border of one polygon to another polygon. However, these polygons overlap.  Thus when I use the Near function, it results in zero because the polygons overlap at some points or one is within a larger one.  I cannot use the Point Distance because I have shapefiles and so I have nothing to choose from in the drop down menu.

Comment: Please tell us precisely what you mean by the "distances between the borders" of two overlapping polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You can create borders by using [Polygon to Line tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003t000000) for each polygon. Then use [Near](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000) tool on these two borders.